# Parsley.js - How to add a value to the required validator

Tags: parsley.js

As a developer integrating parsley.js
I would like to add a value to the standard required validator
so that the message is showing a message like

*"The field email is required"*

where the value in the above example is "email"

```
<input type="text" value="" name="email" data-parsley-required="email">
```

in i18n/en.js

```
window.ParsleyConfig.i18n.de = $.extend(window.ParsleyConfig.i18n.de || {}, {
  [...]
  required:       "The field % is required",
  [...]
});
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply cannot do that. `data-parsley-required` option have a specific API and must handle booleans.

If this is the error message that bothers you, please use `data-parsley-error-message` or `data-parsley-required-error-message`. You could find more info about these options here: http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#psly-ui-for-field

Best